Get_problem while cloning yolov5
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'TBB'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
get the error each time while cloning the yolov5 from github
how to fix it
with proper code or guidence

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

do you get it when you run git clone .. or when you run other command? We can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments)
